# How can I use enum, func and switch so that it receives a data type "month" and returns the numer of the month on swift?

Tags: swift, function, enums, switch-statement

For enumerations, create the months enumeration to define data types based on the months of the year and create the function numberMonths that receive the data type months and return the number of the corresponding month, To return the corresponding month number use switch.

```
enum Moths{
     case January
     case February
     case March
     case April
     case May
     case June
     case July
     case August
     case September
     case October
     case November
     case December
}
```

Here is my fuction and switch

```
func numberMoth (forMoths type: Moths) -> Int{
     switch type {
     case .January:
     print(1)
     case .February:
     print(2)
     case .March:
     print(3)
     case .April:
     print(4)
     case .May:
     print(5)
     case .June:
     print(6)
     case .July:
     print(7)
     case .August:
     print(8)
     case .September:
     pritn(9)
     case .October:
     print(10)
     case .November:
     print(11)
     case .December:
     print(12)
}
```

Swift is new to me and so I hope it's not a very silly question but I hope I'm not doing something wrong.

I thank you in advance for your help, thanks to you I am learning a little more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `print(5)` you can `return 5`. But also, Swift enums can have raw values of `Int`, so you can just do:

```
enum Month: Int {
   case january = 1
   case february
   case march
   ...
}
```

<sup>Note, that Swift convention is to use camelCase for enum cases, variables and properties, and use Capital case for types</sup>

Then you could use `.rawValue` property for the month:

```
let june: Month = .june

let num = june.rawValue // 6
```

Or, if you want that convenience method, you can do that as well:

```
extension Month {
   func numberMonth() -> Int { 
     self.rawValue
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but i need to use enum , func and switch for this proyect.The switch needs to give me the number of the month using the previous things that i mentioned.